# Github committed automatically to submodules

Tags: angular, git, github, .net-core

I've encountered a weird behavior by github which could happened because I am not aware of how the system works. I created a new repository and pushed a visual studio solution including 4 projects.
The folders are:

```
 - D-mail-app (Angular Project) [The one which automatically become submodule]
 - Dmail.API (ASP.net core)
 - Dmail.Core (Class Library .net Core)
 - Dmail.Data (Class Library .net Core)
```

When I did git add . 
and committed all the folders I found out that my D-mail-app folder was added but as submodules. 
It shows the name of the folder but with no content inside. I tried to push it separately but couldn't manage to do that. So eventually I created a different repository for the UI.

I wanted to know if there a reason for this behavior and is it fixable? since its a one project I want to have at the same repository.

Comment: Can you please add the different .ignore files?

Comment: You get a submodule if the sub-folder is already its own Git repository. A Git repository *cannot* contain another Git repository (this is forbidden administratively) and it is unwise (hence administratively forbidden) to include all the files *from* a Git repository inside a containing outer Git repository. It's OK to take one snapshot *out of* some Git repository, move it to a non-repository location, and then surround that with an outer, enclosing, Git repository: now you have just one bigger repository in which there is no submodule, just another set of files as usual.

Comment: @torek thanks for your answer, indeed it cleared few things for me.